# capture updated exchange rate by using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to capture exchange rate from hexun.com,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
urls = 'http://so.hexun.com/default.do?type=forex&key=iskcny'
html = requests.get(urls)
soup = bs(html.text, "html.parser")

s1 = soup.find('span', attrs={"id": "ISKCNYforexprice"})
s2 = soup.find_all("span")
result = [span.get_text() for span in s2]
print(result)
```

below is error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\cur\isk_Rate.py", line 4, in <module>
    html = requests.url(urls).read()
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'url'
```

Comment: Did you mean `requests.get()`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
html = requests.url(urls).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

with

```
html = requests.get(urls)
soup = bs(html.text, "html.parser")
```

Comment: thanks, but it still error, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\cur\isk_Rate.py", line 6, in <module>
    soup = bs4(html.text, "html.parser")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.

I have tried to import bs, but only allow import bs4 and not sucess as well, any suggestion?